# Do I need an article in this sentence

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

I wrote

> However, in most existing treebanks, [a ?]  dependency or  phrase structure is used [to annotate the sentences], depending on the syntax properties of the language.

I am not sure if I need article "a" before *dependency or  phrase structure*, if it is possible I prefer not to have it. (structure can be uncountable/countable)

**Update** This paragraph from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treebank) use them without article, why?! :

> Some treebanks follow a specific linguistic theory in their syntactic annotation (e.g. the BulTreeBank follows HPSG) but most try to be less theory-specific. However, two main groups can be distinguished: treebanks that annotate **phrase structure** (for example the Penn Treebank or ICE-GB) and those that annotate **dependency structure** (for example the Prague Dependency Treebank or the Quranic Arabic Dependency Treebank).

Comment: I'd say it's optional. If I can find some resources, I'll change this into an answer.

Comment: It is optional, but I would advice you to drop the last comma. :) :(

Comment: Can you give the whole paragraph?

Comment: @snailboat  now I can't find the article, but to give  more context, I provided a similar paragraph from Wikipedia

Answer (score 1):

> it is dependency structure and [dependency] plays the adjective role.

I had misunderstood the jargon in the sentence. I've done a bit of research on "treebanks" and "dependency structure". With this new information, I would say the indefinite article **is required**.

This makes your sentence:

> However, in most existing treebanks, a dependency or phrase structure is used to annotate the sentences, depending on the syntax properties of the language.

Using the definite article **the** would be wrong as you are not referencing a *specific* structure.

---

<strike>I'd say the indefinite article here is optional, however if you do include it, I'd include it in front of "phrase structure" too.</strike>

> However, in most existing treebanks, dependency or phrase structure is used, depending on the syntax properties of the language.

> However, in most existing treebanks, **a** dependency or **a** phrase structure is used, depending on the syntax properties of the language.

---

This extract from the Wikipedia article on [Zero Article Marking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-marking_in_English) gives more information on where the article is dropped.

> English also uses no article before a mass noun or a plural noun if the reference is indefinite, a thing that is not specifically identifiable in context.[3] For example:
>   **generic mass noun**: Happiness is contagious.
>   **generic plural noun**: Cars have accelerators.
>   **generic plural noun**: They want equal rights.
>   **indefinite mass noun**: I drink coffee.
>   **indefinite plural noun**: I saw cars.

"Dependancy" isn't any of these however! It is countable. It is singular. It isn't a mass noun. I'm not sure why the article can be dropped here. I'm looking for more resources!

Comment: Thank you, but it is *dependency structure* and structure plays the adjective role, I think we should consider *structure*

Comment: Do you mean that "dependency" is the adjective?

Comment: Yes, it is *the dependency structure or the phrase structure*, and I left out the first structure,  I even suspect I must use *the*

Comment: I updated my question, and referred to an article from Wikipedia where they use zero article but why?